# Prove Complex Inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, complex-numbers

i need to prove given $$|z|=2 \Rightarrow |Im(1-\bar z + z^2)|\le 7$$
$$|Im(1-\bar z + z^2)|\le|1-\bar z + z^2|\tag{1}$$
$$|1-\bar z + z^2|=|-\bar z+1+z^2|\le |-\bar z|+|1+z^2|\le |-\bar z|+|1|+|z^2|\tag{2}$$
$$|-\bar z|+|1|+|z^2| = |z| + |1| + |z|^2 = 7$$

Is the procedure correct?

Comment: I think it's right.

Comment: It looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelRozenberg!

Comment: @aleperno You are welcome!